# Как разместить блок в нише из за разницы высот? [Bootstrap]

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

```
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 black"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 red"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 black"></div>
</div>
```

Получается следующее =>[image: Три разных блока]

Как поднять последний черный блок, что-бы получился своеобразный квадрат разделенный цветом пополам? Левая сторона - черная, вторая - красная. Спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
<div class="rows" style="display: flex;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 black"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 black"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

А с ***.row*** уже играться свойствами flexbox

Answer (score 1):

```css
.black{
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
}
.red{
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="black"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="black"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>


<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Измените принцип вложенности, например так

```
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-6 ">
         <div class="col-lg-12 black"></div>
         <div class="col-lg-12 black"></div>

       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-6 red"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Так не тот же результат выходит...